# Unable to generating client typescript-fetch at https://editor.swagger.io/

Tags: javascript, typescript, documentation-generation, swagger-editor

Hey guys I am having problems to generate client typescript-fetch from https://editor.swagger.io/

When I try to generate typescript client, nothing happen and it shows this on the console

[>console output<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqbWk.png)

it doesn't happen when I try to generate other client.

Is there is something that I can do?

Thank youuu :D

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52306406/edit) to include your code and errors as text within your question, instead of as images. For more information, I'd suggest you read [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Answer (score 1):

The default one at https://editor.swagger.io/ works fine, so without a reporoduceable example they will not be able to help.

> Is there is something that I can do?

You can report the issue *in more detail* (e.g. providing the example API) over here : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues